# What is the probability that Andrew stops after writing squares consecutively?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, contest-math

> Andrew has a fair six-sided die labelled with 1 through 6. He tosses it repeatedly, and on every third roll he writes down the number facing up as long as it is not the 6. He stops as soon as the last two numbers he has written down are squares or one is a prime and the other is a square. What is the probability that he stops after writing squares consecutively?

I previously thought the answer should be $2/11,$ but this doesn't seem to be the case according to an online source, which concluded that the answer was the same as the probability of selecting 2 squares from $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ when selecting two numbers from the set uniformly and at random.

> In the online source, they mentioned that if the (3i)th roll is a six, it could be ignored, though I'm not sure why.

I tried computing both the probability of the event and the probability of the complement in two different ways each. One can think of the regular expressions $SS, S X, P^*X$ for the given event and $X,SP, PP^* X, PP^*S, SX$ for the complementary event. Here, S in the ith position means a square was rolled on the (3i)th roll, a P in the ith position means a prime was rolled on the (3i)th roll, and an X in the ith position means a six was rolled on the (3i)th roll, $P^*$ denotes 0 or more P's. For the probability of the event, we have the following cases: 1) Andrew rolls two squares, 2) he rolls a square, a six, followed by a sequence ending in two squares, 3) he rolls zero or more primes, a six, followed by a sequence ending in two squares. Hence if p is the probability Andrew writes 2 consecutive squares, then $p=1/9 + (1/3\cdot  1/6 + 1/(1-1/2) \cdot 1/6)p,$ which gives $p=2/11.$

Now we consider the complementary event and denote its probability by $q.$ For the desired event to occur, we can only have one of the following cases, where we only consider roll numbers that are a multiple of 3: 1) Andrew rolls at least one prime and then a square, 2) he rolls zero or more primes, a six, followed by a sequence ending in a prime and a square, 3) he rolls a square, zero or more primes, a six, followed by a sequence ending in a prime and a square, 4) he rolls a square and then a prime. Thus we have $q = 1/2/(1-1/2)\cdot 1/3 + 1/3\cdot 1/2 + (1/(1-1/2)\cdot 1/3 \cdot 1/6 + 1/6\cdot 1/(1-1/2))q\Rightarrow q = 9/11.$

> What am I doing wrong in the above approach?

Comment: The "every third roll" part serves no purpose.  Nor does the $6$...better to assume that it is a $5$ sided die.  Note that if you throw a prime first then it is impossible to end with two squares.  Indeed, the only way to end with two squares is to throw them on your first and second trials.

Comment: This is a bizarre question as indeed the “every third roll” is so irrelevant (+1 to above comment) that it makes readers think they have not understood the question, or that there is something missing from the question. I guess the purpose is to introduce intentional distractions to give students practice in isolating the relevant information.

Comment: Andrew does not write down the $6$, so your expressions should be limited to $SS,SP,PP^*S$

Comment: @DanielMathias I think you misunderstood my solution. My solution only considers what Andrew rolled on his (3i)th roll. So my expressions should be fine.

Comment: @lulu thanks, but the whole point of my question is to better understand an alternative approach to solving these sorts of problems, namely one involving recursion. I know the probability is the same as rolling two squares consecutively ignoring the sixes, but the point of my question is to provide an alternative justification as to why the sixes can be ignored in the first place.

Comment: I don't understand.  If you understand what I wrote, then you know the answer is not what you claimed it was.  And I don't understand what recursion you could have in mind...the game is (effectively) over by the second significant toss.  That is to say, the outcome is known by the second significant toss.  What could you do recursion on?

Comment: If you want a more elaborate method, use Markov Chains (which are somewhat like recursions).  Imagine states labeled by the last significant toss (so $\emptyset,\,S,\,P$) and WIN, LOSE.  Now work out the transitions and solve the system in the standard way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As there seems to be some confusion, let me flesh out the quick solution I sketched in the comments.

Define a toss to be "significant" if it occurs in a trial divisible by $3$ and if it is one of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$.  As each toss is independent of all others, these five possible outcomes each have probability $\frac 15$.

We are only interested in the sequence of significant tosses.  As the OP suggested, we'll denote a Square, $\{1,4\}$,  by $S$ and a Prime, $\{2,3,5\}$, by $P$.

Now, if you toss $P$ as your first significant toss you can't win.  Indeed, the significant toss sequence must then have the form $P^nS$ for some $n≥1$ and that means the last two tosses were $PS$, a loss.

If you toss $S$ first then you must toss $S$ second to win, else you lose again.

Thus the only way to win is to toss $SS$ initially, so the probability of winning is $$\boxed {\left(\frac 25\right)^2=\frac 4{25}}$$

Comment: Thanks. Could you check out [this nontrivial probability question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4610818/prove-that-p-n-to-1-2-and-q-n-1-4n-to-1) if you have time? It's from an HMMT team round.

Comment: @user33096  If you post problems from some third part search, be sure to include the link.  Small changes in the problem can easily change it from straight forward to impossible.

Answer (score 0):

- Since he can't write down a $6$, it is as good as not being there, $\;\;\therefore$ equivalent to a five sided die.
- Also, since only the *written* values are considered, we can imagine the game as writing down every throw of the die rather than every third throw without affecting the result.

Let $S$ be a square throw, $(Pr = \frac25),$
$P$ be a prime, $(Pr=\frac35),$
and $N$ be starting state, then we get the equations

$\displaylines{N = 2S/5 +  3P/5 \quad...[I]\\
P = 3P/5 + (2/5)*0 \quad ...[II] \\
S = 3P/5   + (2/5)*1\quad ...[III]}$

Note that in equation $[II]$, we are not allowing the sequence $PS$ because we are interested only in the probability of $SS$

[Solve for N](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=N+%3D+2S%2F5+%2B+3P%2F5+%2C+P%3D3P%2F5+%2C+S%3D3P%2F5%2B%282%2F5%29*1+) which will give
the probability of getting SS from start:$N = \boxed{\frac4{25}}$

---

Comment: @user33096: Happy New Year !  :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is a wrong answer. I'll let it be here because this is an easy mistake to make - please see comments below for why this is wrong

---

Forget the die and consider the written numbers as a sequence.

It is clear that any number in the sequence is one from the set $\{ 1,2,3,4,5 \}$ : each with probability $1/5$.

Probability of the event P prime($2,3,5$) = $3/5$
Probability of the event S square($1,4$) = $2/5$

Let us consider only the last two throws - these are either $\text{SS or SP or PS}$. We're to find the probability that it is $\text{SS}$.

$P(\text{SS | SS or SP or PS}) 
= \dfrac{P(\text{SS})}{P(\text{SS or SP or PS})}
= \dfrac{\frac25 \cdot \frac25}{\frac25 \cdot \frac25 + \frac25 \cdot \frac35 + \frac35 \cdot \frac25}
= \dfrac{4}{16} = \dfrac14 $

Comment: You are assuming that the probability that the sequence ends with a given one of the three possible end states is equal to the probability that two tosses yields that end case, but this is not true.  If you throw a $P$ initially then you MUST end with $PS$ and if you throw an $S$ first you CAN'T end in $PS$ so the probability of ending in $PS$ is $\frac 35$, for example.

Comment: @lulu I've read your answer also. But i don't understand -  Why is the sequence of significant tosses PSS not possible for example?

Comment: Because the game would have ended at $PS$.

Comment: oh right, so the assumption that is wrong is that "the events are independent", right?

Comment: Well, I'd prefer to say that the end states depend on the earlier states.  But, sure.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I misread the question and so my regular expressions were incorrect. One can think of the regular expressions $X^*SX^*S$ for the given event and $X^*P(X^*P)^*X^* S, X^*SX^*P$ for the complementary event. Here, S in the ith position means a square was rolled on the (3i)th roll, a P in the ith position means a prime was rolled on the (3i)th roll, and an X in the ith position means a six was rolled on the (3i)th roll, $P^*$ denotes 0 or more P's. Hence if p is the probability Andrew writes 2 consecutive squares, then $p=1/(1-1/6)\cdot 1/3 \cdot 1/(1-1/6)\cdot 1/3 = 4/25.$

Now we consider the complementary event and denote its probability by $q.$ Thus from the regular expressions we have $q = 1/(1-1/6)\cdot 1/2\cdot (1-1/(1-1/6)\cdot 1/2)^{-1} \cdot 1/(1-1/6)\cdot  1/3 + 1/(1-1/6) \cdot 1/3 \cdot 1/(1-1/6)\cdot 1/2 = 21/25.$