# Prove that $p_n\to 1/2,$ and $q_n/(1/4)^n\to -1$

Tags: calculus, probability, combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

Here is problem 10 of [13th Annual Harvard-MIT Mathematics Tournament Team Round A 2010](https://hmmt-archive.s3.amazonaws.com/tournaments/2010/feb/team1/problems.pdf)

> Call a 2n-digit base-10 number special if we can split its digits into two multisets of size n such that the sum of the numbers in the two sets is the same. Let $p_n$ be the probability that a randomly chosen 2n-digit number is special. We allow leading zeroes in 2n-digit numbers.

1. Prove that $p_n\to 1/2$ as $n\to\infty$.
2. Let $q_n=p_n-1/2.$ Prove that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} q_n/(1/4)^n = -1.$

> There is an official solution to this problem, though I don't understand it fully. I was therefore thinking of requesting an answer here in the hopes that I'd understand it better. For convenience, [here](https://hmmt-archive.s3.amazonaws.com/tournaments/2010/feb/team1/solutions.pdf) is a link to the official solution. To reiterate, it is not necessary to answer all of the questions I ask here, though it may be easier than coming up with an alternative solution to this problem.

> The main thing I don't understand about the solution to part a is why their proof shows that $p_n$ converges to $1/2$.

> The proof of the second part of this question given in the official solution is quite hard for me to understand. In particular, I have the following questions about the solution. It seems that I can't fully understand the proof of part (a), which is why I can't seem to prove claims that follow from a similar argument to part 1 in this question.

> Edit: I've removed some previous questions so that this post no longer has as many questions.

1. Why is a number good if it has any odd digits? Again, this seems similar to the proof of part a).
2. If there are no odd digits, why does the sum being divisible by 4 imply the number is good?

> The only change from the official solution that I think should be made is that 8-k should be replaced with 4-k.

> Here is my take of the case where the sum of the digits is congruent to 0 modulo 4 and all the digits are even, where balancing argument A refers to Apass.Jack's final algorithm in his solution:

Also, even if there are no odd digits, if the sum of the digits is divisible by 4, then the number is balanced. Indeed, in this case, the number of even numbers congruent to 2 modulo 4 must be even. We first set aside 10 occurrences of the digits 0,4,6,8. We then perform balancing argument A on the remaining digits, which still have a sum congruent to 0 modulo 4. Then if $S_1$ and $S_2$ are the resulting sets of digits, and $s_i$ denotes the sum of all numbers in $S_i$ for $i=1,2,$ we have $s_1 + s_2 \equiv 0\mod 4$ and both $s_1$ and $s_2$ are even, so $s_1 - s_2\equiv -2s_2\equiv 0\mod 4.$ Let $d = |s_1-s_2|.$ Suppose $s_1 \leq s_2$. We now add $(10-d/2)/2$ occurrences of the two numbers 4 and 6 and $(10+d/2)/2$ occurrences of the two numbers 0 and 8 to $S_1$. Finally, we add $(10+d/2)/2$ occurrences of the two numbers 4 and 6 and $(10-d/2)/2$ occurrences of 0 and 8 to $S_2.$ Then the difference between the new sums $s_1$ and $s_2$ is now zero.

Comment: Please edit to provide a link to the source of the problem.

Comment: The second condition sounds like it is suggesting the only (asymptotically significant) obstruction to being special, assuming the digit sum is even, is if all the digits are even (in which case it reduces to the same problem with every digit halved).

Comment: Convergence to $1/2$ is easily established by showing that the probability of *not* having at least $8$ 0-digits and 1-digits converges to $0$ (since the expected number of each digit is $n/5$, this is certainly expected and should be a routine calculation).

Comment: Sorry about the many questions. I'm having a hard time understanding the solution. I know it's discouraged to ask many questions, so if requested, I guess I can split this question up into two questions with separate parts.

Comment: @user33096 yes, that "$8-k$" in the official solution should have been "$4-k$".

Answer (score 2):

For two functions $f(n)$ and $g(n)$,

- "$f(n)\ll g(n)$" will mean $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}=0$.  We also say $f(n)$ is negligible to $g(n)$.
- "$f(n)\to g(n)$" will mean $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}=1$, the same as in the official solution and the question. We also say $f(n)$ is asymptotic to $g(n)$.

We will use "balanced" and "unbalanced" numbers instead of "special" and "not special" numbers.

A useful fact is that exponentiation is more significant than polynomial i.e. $m^b\ll a^m$ for all $a>1$ and $b$. For example,

$$\lim_{m\to\infty}\frac{m^{999999}}{1.000001^m}=0 $$

---

> 1. How does the proof in the official solution show that $p_n\to 1/2$?

The number of $2n$-digit numbers that have at most $7$ $0$'s is $$\sum_{k=0}^{7}{2n\choose k}(10-1)^{2n-k}<8(2n)^79^{2n}=8\cdot\frac{(2n)^7}{(10/9)^{2n}}10^{2n}.$$
Since $(2n)^7\ll (10/9)^{2n}$, the LHS $\ll 10^{2n}$.
Similarly, the number of $2n$-digit numbers that have at most $7$ $1$'s is $\ll 10^{2n}$. Note $10^{2n}$ is the number of all $2n$-digit numbers since leading zeros are allowed.  Hence, the number of $2n$-digit numbers that have at least $8$ $0$'s and at least $8$ $1$'s is asymptotic to $10^{2n}$.

- Since half of all $10^{2n}$ $2n$-digit numbers have even digit-sum, the number of $2n$-digit numbers that have at least $8$ $0$'s and at least $8$ $1$'s and even digit-sum is asymptotic to half of $10^{2n}$.
- Similarly, the number of $2n$-digit numbers that have at least $8$ $0$'s and at least $8$ $1$'s and odd digit-sum is also asymptotic to half of $10^{2n}$.

Note that the former numbers are balanced while the latter numbers are not. Hence $p_n\to\frac12$.

> 2. If it's true that the configuration that contributes the vast majority of unbalanced even-digit-sum numbers is when all numbers are even and the sum is 2 mod 4, or such a configuration with all digits increased by 1, then why does it imply $q_n$ is asymptotic to $-1/2\cdot 2\cdot (1/2)^{2n}=(-1/4)^n$?

All $\frac1210^{2n}$ odd-digit-sum $2n$-digit numbers are unbalanced.
There are $\frac1210^{2n}$ even-digit-sum $2n$-digit numbers

The number of $2n$-digit numbers  where all digits are even is $5^{2n}$. Starting from $0=\underbrace{00\cdots0}_{2n}$, every other one of them is $2\!\!\mod\!4$. So $(5^{2n}-1)/2$ of them are $2\!\!\mod\!4$, which is asymptotic to $\frac12(\frac14)^n10^{2n}$. Adding the "configuration with all digits increased by $1$", the number of "vast majority of unbalanced even-digit-sum numbers" is asymptotic to $2\cdot\frac12(\frac14)^n10^{2n}=(\frac14)^n10^{2n}$. Hence so is $-q_n10^{2n}$, the number of unbalance even-digit-sum numbers.

> 3. Why is the asymptotic probability that there are at most 4 digits that occur more than 10 times much smaller than $\left(\frac12\right)^n$?

Please note that $\left(\frac12\right)^n$ in the solution as well as in the quote above should have been  $\left(\frac14\right)^n$. $\ \left(\frac12\right)^n$ is not small enough to support the conclusion that $r=\frac14$.

The reason is $4<5=\frac{10}{2}$.

Here is the detail. The number of $2n$-digit numbers where $1,2,3,4,5,6$ appear $10, 10,10,10,10,10$ times respectively is ${2n\choose 60}{60\choose{10,10,10,10,10,10}}(10-6)^{2n-60},$ which is $<(2n)^{60}4^{2n}=(2n)^{60}\left(\frac45\right)^{2n}5^{2n}\ll5^{2n}$.

If we replace $1,2,3,4,5,6$ with another choice of at least $6$ distinct digits and $10,10,10,10,10,10$ with another choice of frequencies no more than $10$, the number of correspondingly-restricted $2n$-digit numbers is also negligible to $5^{2n}$. Since there are at most $2^{10}11^{10}$ replacements (I am over-counting a lot, but that does not matter as long as the number of replacements is bounded independently of $n$), the number of all correspondingly-restricted $2n$-digit numbers together is still negligible to $5^{2n}=\frac1{4^n}10^{2n}$. That is, the asymptotic probability that there are at most $4$ digits that occur more than $10$ times much smaller than $\frac1{4^n}$.

> 4. Why is it true that if any two digits occurring at least 10 times are consecutive, an even-digit-sum number is balanced?

Suppose $\ell$ is an even-digit-sum number with $\ge10$ $a$'s and $\ge10$ $(a+1)$'s. The algorithm below will show $\ell$ is balanced.

1. Put aside $10\ $ $a$'s and $10\ $ $(a+1)$'s.
2. Initially no numbers are on the left side and the right side. For the the remaining digits in $\ell$, repeatedly put the largest remaining one on the side with less sum. If the sums of both sides are equal, on the left side.
3. Let $d$ be the difference of the sum of digits on the left side and the sum of digits on the right side. It's absolute value cannot be greater than 10. It must be an even number. Put $(10-d)/2\ $ $a$'s and $(10+d)/2\ $ $(a+1)$'s on the side with smaller sum or any side if the sums are equal; put the remaining $a$'s and $(a+1)$'s on the other side. Now the sums of both sides are equal.

The approach above may help resolve the last three questions.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm still struggling to understand how to apply your argument to the case where there is at least one odd digit or the case when there are only even digits and the digit sum is 0 modulo 4. Could you provide a general algorithm to deal with these cases?

Comment: Please do not delete any answer that I have written. The answers are not only for you, also for other readers such as my students. The answers might be trivial. However, this is exactly why many problems in math contests are interesting. They become trivial once a nice solution is presented. Many problems in the International Mathematical Olympiad, even the last ones are trivial once a solution is presented, especially to people like you. However, they can still  be eye-openers for vastly many other students or even professionals.

Comment: Just in case it is not clear, I am here not only to help you, but also help lots of others, when I am writing each single answer for questions raised by you. That is the design of this website.

Comment: By the way, thanks for raising interesting questions tagged contest-math. You have done wonderfully! I have been enjoying very much reading your questions with detailed analysis.

Comment: In particular, I spent quite some time finding my first solution to solve that number theory problem. Still, I suspected my solution might be superseded by an even better solution. Then about half an hour later, I was able to find an "utterly trivial application of induction", which identifies and uses an interesting property of the group of ${x\choose i}$'s.

Comment: Thanks. But you still haven't addressed the fact that I don't quite understand how to deal with the case where there are some odd digits, which I find frustrating. I've made an edit to my question showing my progress on the case where there are only even digits and the sum of the digits is congruent to 0 modulo 4.

Comment: I've also modified my question so that there are no longer so many parts. The question only asks about things that I still don't fully understand. That way, at least this question won't seem too "packed." Feel free to modify your answer. Also feel free to join [my chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141900/chat-room-1) if you think there's more to discuss.